# I am getting two error messages before startup is finished

Tags: boot, 16.04

When I start my laptop normally, it always showed only a message

```
sda clean 9483989/237839829 clean 0438/23989 blocks
```

during startup.

As it looked like harddrive information I thought this was displaying disk usage, but over time it started increasing, and now another message I don't understand has started to appear:

```
[OK] Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill1
```

What is this? Am I safe?

Answer (score 2):

As far as the

```
sda clean 9483989/237839829 clean 0438/23989 blocks
```

message goes, that's completely normal as 16.04 runs `fsck` on boot. It's just telling you that your `ext4` filesystem is clean and there aren't any orphaned `inodes` or anything like that.

---

And regarding:

```
[OK] Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill1
```

That message is referring to the physical Wi-Fi / Bluetooth switch on the side of your laptop. There is a way to override the hardware switch IIRC, so that message probably means the kernel is checking the state of the switch so it can respect it.

---

Bottom line, both of those messages are normal and you have nothing to worry about :)